# Puzzling on probabilistic programming language in Julia, Turing.jl and Distributions.jl

Tags: julia, probabilistic-programming

I am currently working on a simple Bayesian problem in which my likelihood is the product of `N` Poisson distributions, so I got the following:

```
likelihood(x) ~ product_i(Poisson(mean_i))
```

where `x` is a vector, representing the variables, and the product on the other side run over the dimension (from `i` to `N`). `mean_i` is the mean associated to the variables `x_i` in the vector `x`.

As far as I have understood Turing and Distributions, I think that the following is the 'correct' code part for the likelihood:

```
vector_x = [x for x in variables]
vector_x ~ Product([Poisson(mean_i) for mean_i in means]
```

where `means` is a vector containing the various means associated to each poisson process.
Is it correct? :D

Comment: Please be more specific. Have you tried it out? Any errors or wrong results?

Comment: Well, first thanks for typo improvements.
The code doesn't raise any errors, so from this point it is at least correct.
The problem is that I am currently cross-checking the analysis of some other people, doing the same thing, and the results are not in agreement. So I was thinking if maybe the definition of product likelihood is incorrect since I have used Turining and Distributions for other cross-checking and worked perfectly.

Comment: I know Turing quite well, but I fail to see a question. It is syntactically correct, although containing some weird things. You better state the complete inference problem.

Comment: E.g., you probably should use `vector_x ~ arraydist(Poisson.(means))`. The line before is basically a no-op.

Comment: with `arraydist` are you referring to creating an array of distributions?
My puzzling is just in using `Product` to resemble what I write on paper. Just this

Comment: `arraydist` is basically `Product`, but provided by Turing (I think from DistributionsAD.jl?) and may allow for some optimizations. Other than that, yes, the `Product` part is fine.

Comment: Maybe a better strategy is to ask on the Turing channels of the Julia slack or Zulip, or on Discourse.